# Separating Concerns into Methods

Tags: apex, trigger, update, method

I'm trying to write better code and make it clearer what each function does and build tests that cover it. I have a method in a triggerhandler class that updates a date field when another date field is changed. It works in that the field is updated successfully but it's all in one method. I wrote the below code to separate each piece out into multiple methods. 
I have two questions, one how do you pass variables from one method to another? In one method I filter the records down into a list, then in the next method I take that list and do a query of a related object. I get an error when I try to compile the below code with 'Variable does not exist: parents' in my tryUpdate Method. 'parents' is a map that I defined in the previous method but the new method cannot see it.

Second, does this look functionally correct? Is this the approach that I should be making?

```
    private void hasDateRangeChanged(Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> newMap, Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> oldMap)
{
    List<OpportunityLineItem> dateRangeChanged = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    for (OpportunityLineItem item : newMap.values())
    {
        if ((item.Start_Date__c != oldMap.get(item.id).Start_Date__c) || (item.End_Date__c != oldMap.get(item.id).End_Date__c))
        dateRangeChanged.add(item);
    }
}

/*
    * MethodName        : getContractTerm
    * param             : Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> oldMapOpp, List<Opportunity> newListOpp
    * Description       : This method will get the ContactTerm__c field from the related Opportunity. 
*/

private void getContractTerm(List<OpportunityLineItem> dateRangeChanged)
{
    List<OpportunityLineItem> items = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    items.add(dateRangeChanged);
    Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (OpportunityLineItem item : items) 
        parentIds.add(item.OpportunityId);
        Map<Id, Opportunity> parents = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, ContractTerm__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :parentIds]);
}

/*
    * MethodName        : tryUpdate
    * param             : Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> oldMapOpp, List<Opportunity> newListOpp
    * Description       : This method will try to update the Start_Date_Renewal__c and End_Date_Reenwal__c fields. 
*/

private void tryUpdate(List<OpportunityLineItem> dateRangeChanged)
{
    List<OpportunityLineItem> safeupdate = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    safeupdate.add(dateRangeChanged);
    List<Opportunity> opps = new List<Opportunity>();
    opps.add(parents);
    try
    {
        for(OpportunityLineItem oli: safeupdate.values())
        {
            oli.Start_Date_Renewal__c = oli.Start_Date__c.addMonths(Integer.valueOf(opps.get(oli.OpportunityId).ContractTerm__c)).toStartOfMonth();
            oli.End_Date_Renewal__c = oli.End_Date__c.addMonths(Integer.valueOf(opps.get(oli.OpportunityId).ContractTerm__c)).toStartOfMonth();
        }
    }
    catch (DmlException dmx)
    {
        // womp womp
    }
}

/*
    * MethodName        : doUpdate
    * param             : List<Opportunity> newListOpp
    * Description       : This method will do the update of the records 
*/


private void doUpdate(List<OpportunityLineItem> dateRangeChanged)
{
    List<OpportunityLineItem> toUpdate = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    toUpdate.addAll(oli);
    tryUpdate(toUpdate);
}
```

UPDATE:

So since I have to return a result to reference in the next method I need to use static? Which means in my first method it would be:

```
public static hasDateRangeChanged(Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> newMap, Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> oldMap)
{
    List<OpportunityLineItem> dateRangeChanged = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    for (OpportunityLineItem item : newMap.values())
    {
        if ((item.Start_Date__c != oldMap.get(item.id).Start_Date__c) || (item.End_Date__c != oldMap.get(item.id).End_Date__c))
        dateRangeChanged.add(item);
    }
    return dateRangeChanged;
}
```

Comment: Your return types should tell you something about what you're trying to accomplish. Right now they're all `void`. For example, your filter method should return a `List<OpportunityLineItem>`.

Comment: Also, your syntax looks like it should not compile. You can't add a list to a list, you need to use `addAll` in those cases where you actually need a separate list.

Comment: @DanWooding Please edit your post (just put `Update` or `Edit` followed by the additional comments and code at bottom of your post) when you're posting code like in your comment above. Those kinds of comments are essentially unreadable without copying and pasting into an external editor.

Comment: Yes, it does make more sense for the methods to be `static`, but more importantly you need to specify a return type. It's listed as `data_type` in [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining_methods.htm).

Comment: Tried to write an answer, but I'm finding that this question has too many issues to to tackle to make a coherent and concise answer. For what it's worth, In my opinion, I think the code you've shared goes too far in trying to separate concerns. Right now, your code has more lines dedicated to _preparing_ to do something than it spends _actually doing it_.

Comment: Is there a way to pause this question or is best to delete it? I have to rethink this.